# Behavior of the parameter 'throttle_secs' in tf.estimator.EvalSpec for use in tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow's train_and_eval function as in the [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/train_and_evaluate). Therefore i create an instance of tf.estimator.EvalSpec, according to

```
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=...,throttle_secs=60).
```

According to its [documentation](http://eval_spec%20=%20tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=lambda:%20tf_data_utils.monuseg_input_func(mdl_info,train=False,normalize=True),throttle_secs=60*5)) the explanation of the parameter throttle_secs states that

"Of course, evaluation does not occur if no new checkpoints are available, hence, this is the minimum."

However, i observe a different behavior. If there is no new checkpoint and evaluation should be triggered according to the passed parameter a new checkpoint is created and evaluation is performed.

Is this a bug or am i missing something here?

Comment: I can confirm that this happens in my case as well and is very frustrating! I want checkpoints at SPECIFIC training steps, and this one keeps triggering. I'm running on TF 1.8